# image_to_string doesn't work in Mac

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to follow this example of pytesser ([link](https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/wiki/README)) in a Mac Maverick.

```
>>> from pytesser import *
>>> im = Image.open('phototest.tif')
>>> text = image_to_string(im)
```

But, in the last line I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pytesser.py", line 31, in image_to_string
    call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
  File "pytesser.py", line 21, in call_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But, I don't understand what I should do. The file phototest is in the same folder I'm running the script. How to fix this?

UPDATE:

When I try

```
brew install tesseract
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
Error: You must `brew link libtiff libpng jpeg' before tesseract can be installed
```

Comment: It looks like your script has problems launching a process... and it looks like the same problem described in https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/wiki/README
The distribution comes with a Windows executable and that won't work on Mac. As the Linux people there mentioned, you likely to need to supply a tessact executable.

Comment: Got it. But can I do this?

Comment: I'm sure it's doable but I don't know the details: the question should be tagged for tessact users.

Comment: Ok, already tagged tesseract topic

Comment: you can install tesseract with `brew install tesseract`

Comment: I tried, but I get an error message. I updated my question with the error message. Take a look please.

Comment: I am having a similar issue right now. Was this issue ever resolved? Can you post the solution if it was?

Comment: When I run a "brew install tesseract" again, then it gives me a warning: Warning: tesseract-3.02.02_3 already installed, it's just not linked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually had the same error as you, which is how I found this post.  I also have the solution to my problem, because you gave it to me!

I was seeing:

```
ryan.davis$ python tesseract.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tesseract.py", line 52, in <module>
    print (image_to_string(big))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Want to know what I had to do to fix this?  Exactly what you tried: `brew install tesseract`  I had installed the tesseract python library, but hadn't installed it at the system level.  So that solves my problem.  How about yours?

I think you might have been distracted by this:

> Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed. Software
>   installed with other package managers causes known problems for
>   Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try
>   again.

And not noticed your answer was already provided in the brew response:

> You must brew link libtiff libpng jpeg before tesseract can be
>   installed.

So do:

```
brew link libtiff 
brew link libpng 
brew link jpeg
```

Then:

```
brew install tesseract
```

Finally:

```
:)
```

Comment: It works for me Thank You!! Mac OS High Sierra, python 3 =)