# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory using pytesser

Tags: python, error-handling, python-tesseract, pytesser

This is my problem, I want to use pytesser to get a picture's contents. My operating system is Mac OS 10.11, and I have already installed PIL, pytesser, tesseract-ocr engine, and other supporting libraries like libpng and so on. But when I run my code, as below, error occurs.

```
from pytesser import *
import os
image = Image.open('/Users/Grant/Desktop/1.png')
text = image_to_string(image)
print text
```

Next is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Grant/Documents/workspace/image_test/image_test.py",    line 10, in <module>
text = image_to_string(im)
File   "/Users/Grant/Documents/workspace/image_test/pytesser/pytesser.py", line   30, in image_to_string
call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
File "/Users/Grant/Documents/workspace/image_test/pytesser/pytesser.py", line 21, in call_tesseract
retcode = subprocess.call(args)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Besides, tesseract-ocr engine runs well on my Mac, I can run it in terminal and get the result. Below is the test picture result.
[tesseract result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPPHb.png)

Can anyone help me with this question,please?

Comment: Have you tried using \\ instead of / ?

Comment: I just tried, it does not work. It returns an error message" IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\Users\\Grant\\Desktop\\1.png' "

Comment: You need to install Tesseract OCR engine and provide its path.
[Same problem discussed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652335/pytesseract-error-windows-error-error-2/46363594#46363594)

Answer (score 14):

Luckily, I solved this one.

At first, I run the command

```
pip install pytesseract
```

to install the package.

But I get the error message of 'No such file or directory using pytesser'.

Then I read this link: [image_to_string doesn't work in Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049425/image-to-string-doesnt-work-in-mac)
So, just run the following script:

```
brew link libtiff 
brew link libpng 
brew link jpeg
brew install tesseract
```

Worked for me ~

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, but i managed to convert image to string.
using `apt` Advanced package tool should do the trick:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

and if you can't use it in a python script just do this:

```
from os import system

system("tesseract -l eng /image.png text.txt")
```

Answer (score 8):

Open file **pytesseract.py**.

Mine is in `/Users/yourUser/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py`

Change `tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'` to `tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/bin/tesseract'`

Comment: I tried linking and changing paths over and over, none of this worked. This was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: `# CHANGE THIS IF TESSERACT IS NOT IN YOUR PATH, OR IS NAMED DIFFERENTLY`, just a line ahead the involded line :-) so, adding tesseract to the `$PATH` would make it work too without touch the file. Once updated, you'll need to edit again, so the best if you add it to path at first time. Case of mine the binary is called `pytesseract` so none will work unless you add the proper name at all.

Comment: @em3nda What do you mean with your last sentence? Are you saying changing Path doesn't work for you? Despite my path having the bin folder to tesseract, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting exception because subprocess isn't able to find the binaries (tesser executable).

The installation is a 3 step process:

1.**Download/Install system level libs/binaries**:

For various OS here's the [help](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#installation). For MacOS you can directly install it using brew.

> Install Google Tesseract OCR (additional info how to install the
>   engine on Linux, Mac OSX and Windows). You must be able to invoke the
>   tesseract command as tesseract. If this isn’t the case, for example
>   because tesseract isn’t in your PATH, you will have to change the
>   “tesseract_cmd” variable at the top of tesseract.py. Under
>   Debian/Ubuntu you can use the package tesseract-ocr. For Mac OS users.
>   please install homebrew package tesseract.

- Bash script for [**installing tesseract-ocr on RHEL/CentOS 7**](https://github.com/EisenVault/install-tesseract-redhat-centos)
- Using `yum` - from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33378145/1384641) - `/usr/bin/yum --enablerepo epel-testing install tesseract.x86_64`
- A manual installation guide for CentOS - [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36999782/1384641).

---

2.**Install Python package**

```
pip install pytesseract
```

---

3.**Finally, you need to have tesseract binary in you PATH**.

Or, you can set it at run-time:

```
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '<path-to-tesseract-bin>'
```

**The default path 'd be `/usr/local/bin/tesseract`**

Comment: The third point is the most relavant for this question. `$ which tesseract` will give the actual path of tesseract bin, copy that into `'path/to/bin'`. Thank You.

Comment: *`path/to/bin/tesseract`

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem twice, for both MacOS and Ubuntu. This worked with me. Hoping it can help.

First, open Terminal, then:

- Ubuntu: run "sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr"
- MacOS: run "brew install tesseract". If you can not use "brew", run this command first then try again: "ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Answer (score 2):

You need to install tesseract-ocr:

**sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr**

And in the script

```
    from PIL import Image
    import os
    import pytesseract

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(os.path.abspath('test.png')))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the case for everybody but I was having a similar issue and it was due to getting errors when installing tesseract.
I kept getting the error message:

```
Making install in ccutil
/bin/sh: /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

This was due to me having previously renamed /Applications/Xcode to /Applications/Xcode 8 in order to make it easier for myself to distinguish between different Xcode versions installed on my system.

I temporarily renamed it back to /Applications/Xcode then ran the command

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Then finally tried to reinstall tesseract and thankfully got no error messages this time.

```
brew install tesseract --all-languages
```

Now Python code runs fine and I get no "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" error message.