# File tesseract.exe does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed the `pytesseract` library using

```
pip install pytesseract
```

When I tried to use the `image_to_text` method, it gave me a

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system can not find the file specified

I googled it and found that I should change something in the pytesseract.py file and the line

```
tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'
```

should become

```
tesseract_cmd = path_to_folder_that_contains_tesseractEXE + 'tesseract'
```

I searched and haven't found any `tesseract.exe` files in my Python folder, I then reinstalled the library, but the file still wasn't there. Finnally, I replaced the line by:

```
tesseract_cmd = path_to_folder_that_contains_pytesseractEXE + 'pytesseract'
```

and my program threw:

> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: python pytesseract.py [-l lang] input_file')

What can I do make my programm work?

P.S Here is my programm code :

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

im = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Филипп\Desktop\ImageToText_Python\NoName.png') 
print(im)

txt = image_to_string(im)
print(txt)
```

Full Traceback of first attempt :

```
File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/ImageToText.py", line 10, in <module>
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in 
image_to_string config=config)
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in 
run_tesseract proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__ restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]The system can not find the file specified
```

Full Traceback of second attempt

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ImageToText.py", line 6, in <module> txt = image_to_string(im)
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 125, in image_to_string
raise TesseractError(status, errors)
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: python pytesseract.py [-l lang] input_file')
```

Comment: What was the full traceback of your initial attempt?

Comment: @DavidG Added it to my question

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822195/windowserror-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-for-pytesserac/44822322#44822322) answer has a link in the comments to download the .exe. This might help you

Comment: @DavidG It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [project's README](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract):

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
# Include the above line, if you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH
# Example tesseract_cmd: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test-european.jpg'), lang='fra'))
```

So, you have to make sure tesseract.exe is on your computer (for example by installing Tesseract-OCR), then add the containing folder to your PATH environment variable, or declare it's location using `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd` attribute

Comment: They should add the "Tesseract-OCR installation" step to the pytesseract documentaion.

Answer (score 4):

For people in the same case as me: [here](https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_tesseract-ocr-alt/downloads/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe/) is a tesseract-OCR downloader. After you finish the download, go to the path you've chosen, there should be a file named `tesseract.exe`, copy the path to this file and paste it into `pytesseract.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using windows OS - you have to install tesseract-ocr from this [link](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki) (3.05.01 is the stable version and supported for foreign language extraction). And add the path(where you installed the software) to the environment variable.
2. If you are using ubuntu OS  - in terminal type "sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr"
3. Pytesseract is python wrapper that helps you to access this tesseract-ocr software.

Note 1: if you want to extract foreign languages then you have to include [tessdata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) files in the installed path.

Note 2: Python 2 will not have good support on foreign language extraction, so better go with python 3.