# WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified for pytesseract

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr

I am trying to do OCR using pytesseract but getting an Windowserror. Kindly help.

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Loading the images

```
im = Image.open('image_112472.jpg') # the second one
im.load()
```

Printing the text

```
print(image_to_string(im,lang='eng'))
```

I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "C:/Users/amuly/PycharmProjects/P1/Teeth_detection/test1.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(image_to_string(im,lang='eng'))
  File "C:\Users\amuly\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\amuly\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\amuly\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Users\amuly\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure tesseract.exe is on your computer (for example by installing Tesseract-OCR), then add the containing folder to your PATH environment variable, or declare it's location using

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd attribute
```