# No such file or directory: 'tesseract': 'tesseract' even though where to find tesseract is specified in pytesseract.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

So I have been working on this problem for awhile and while others have had questions similar to this but nothing has worked for me:

I am trying to use pytesseract for a project and I have it installed under `User/Environments/testEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/`

I have tesseract installed under `usr/local/bin`

I have gone into `Users/User/Environments/testEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py` and changed `tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'` to `tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/bin/tesseract'` as suggested here: [OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory using pytesser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609773/oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-using-pytesser)

This did not work. I tried to run this:

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('screenshot.png')
img.load()
i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print (i)
```

and I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Environments/testEnv/testTess.py", line 26, in <module>
    i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract': 'tesseract'
```

This is telling me that tesseract can't be found even though I specified in `pytesseract.py`. This befuddles me.

Note: You can probably tell but I am using a virtualenv - could this be an issue due to the fact that tesseract is not in the environment but pytesseract is?

I am using mac osx and python3.6.

I am new to coding and I simply cannot find a solution to this issue.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I have now re-downloaded tesseract and tried this again and also tried putting tesseract here: `/Users/User/Environments/testEnv/bin/tesseract/3.05.01/bin/tesseract`
so that is is within the environment in case that was an issue.

I still cannot make anything work!
Absolutely any suggestions would help.

FINAL UPDATE:
I gave up on the environment and deleted it and program worked.

Comment: Did you mean `/usr/local/bin/tesseract` instead of `usr/local/bin/tesseract`?

Comment: @quartata I meant to put that. Sorry.

Comment: So Sad, you did not get any help, from the last and only place we would expect to not fail us.

Comment: These answers helped me, I have a similar issue. From the link you have given 1. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35736752/5986651) and 2. [3rd point in this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46420593/5986651). I solved my issue as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829307/emacs-python-not-able-to-find-package-module/49866388#49866388)

Answer (score 9):

You should firstly install `tesseract-ocr` like this:

on Linux:
`sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`

on mac:
`brew install tesseract`

For more information, see: [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/03/installing-tesseract-for-ocr/)

Comment: brew suggests ' brew install tesseract-lang ' for other languages support too

Comment: and for windows?

Answer (score 1):

For me below steps worked in Google Colab:

```
!pip install pytesseract

import pytesseract

!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

Answer (score -2):

on mac: you firs install brew, 
copy and paste:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

after:

```
brew install tesseract -- all languages
```

fonds: