# Emacs python not able to find package/module

Tags: python, emacs, anaconda, tesseract, python-tesseract

### Problem

My tesseract (tesserocr) is not found by the emacs python interpreter, but I am able to use tesseract on the terminal as well as in my Spyder installation. Emacs python interpreter is able to import pytesseract, but not find tesserocr. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/eghx/agent18/project-gym/tests/thresholding.py", line 34, in image_to_string2
    print(image_to_string(img_open))
  File "/home/eghx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract-0.1.7-py3.6.egg/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
  File "/home/eghx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract-0.1.7-py3.6.egg/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
  File "/home/eghx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/eghx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract': 'tesseract'
```

when I run

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

However I don't get this error when I open EMACS from a terminal instead of the desktop. It appears that the path variable is inherited differently in the desktop version and terminal version of emacs. ODD!

### Explanation

I have anaconda installation here:`/path/to/anaconda3`

I have added this line to my init file to run this particular python installation

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/path/to/anaconda3/bin/python")
```

I installed both pytesseract and tesserocr using `conda install`

`which tesseract` gives:

```
/path/to/anaconda3/bin/tesseract
```

`$ echo $PATH` gives:

```
/path/to/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lo....
```

### What I did

I copied the sys.path from the working Spyder IDE to emacs python interpreter and still didn't work.

I looked around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609773/oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-using-pytesser?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but the top answer does not pertain to my case, as my $PATH variable contains the necessary path.

Can someone guide me? I am a noob. I have emacs 27 and ubuntu 16 and conda 4.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible duplicate of [OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory using pytesser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609773/oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-using-pytesser?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46420593/5986651) was found as per the 3rd point in the link, quoted below:

```
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'path-to-tesseract-including-bin'
```

In my case,

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/home/anaconda3/bin/tesseract'
```

This is only a temporary hack to get `image_to_string` to work, by typing the above in every file.

Why the `$PATH` variable having the `/home/anaconda3/bin` is not enough to get it to work sufficiently is not known. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35736752/5986651) seems to be a slighty long-term-temporary solution.